Removing covariates from love plot after multiple imputation and propensity matching
I have used mice to create a series of multiply imputed datasets and then applied MatchThem to match on a number of covariates. I am trying to use the love.plot function from cobalt to create a love plot, but I want to omit one of the variables from the plot as my data set has lots of matching variables and the love plot is too busy.
In the example below I want to drop the variable "married" from the love plot. Is there a way to do this?
My code is:
data("lalonde_mis", package = "cobalt")
set.seed(100)

#Generate imputed data sets
m <- 10 #number of imputed data sets
imp.out <- mice::mice(lalonde_mis, m = m, print = FALSE) 


#Performing propensity score matching in each imputation
match.out <- MatchThem::matchthem(nodegree ~ age + race + 
                              re74 + re75, datasets = imp.out,
                           exact = "married",
                           method = "nearest",
                           caliper = 0.2,
                           distance = "glm")

# Removing the married variable from match.out
match.out$object$data$married <- NULL 

love.plot(match.out, threshold = .05, stats = "m",
      abs = FALSE,
      stars = "std", 
      which.imp = .none, agg.fun = "mean",
      drop.distance = TRUE) `


To give a solution that doesn't require to to modify the ggplot object:
Just use the formula interface to love.plot(). That's what it was designed for.
love.plot(nodegree ~ age + race + re74 + re75,
          data = imp.out,
          weights = match.out,
          threshold = .05, stats = "m",
          abs = FALSE,
          stars = "std", 
          which.imp = .none, agg.fun = "mean")


You can specify exactly the variables you want in the plot by supplying them to the formula.

Ah that also works, thanks very much Noah. I had not realised that I should use the imputed data in the "data =" part of the command, but the weights from the matched dataset in the "weights =" part. But that is all now clear. Thanks for your help!

One thing you can do is use ggplot_build to extract the data and get rid of the variables you don't want to plot/rename the underlying variables.
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


out = cobalt::love.plot(match.out, threshold = .05, stats = "m",
      abs = FALSE,
      stars = "std", 
      which.imp = .none, agg.fun = "mean",
      drop.distance = TRUE) 

plot_data = ggplot_build(out)

sans_marriage = plot_data$plot$data |>
  filter(var != 'married')

ggplot(sans_marriage, aes(x = stat, y = var, color = Sample)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = .05, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -0.05, linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme_classic()


Created on 2024-10-25 with reprex v2.1.1

That looks great. Thanks so much Josh!
